# How do I segregate multiple files based on file size into a sub directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have a bunch of video files which I would like to segregate based on file size I have decided.

Example:

Folder *BB* has 15 files of various file size.

I have sub folder set as:

1. `less than 100 MB     -- folder A`
2. `100 MB to 500 MB     -- folder B`
3. `more than 500 MB     -- folder C`

So instead of manually doing it can it be done via Bash or a script.

I have a general idea that `find` command and a proper if else would work, but have no idea how to script it.

Anyway, a general programming frame would be:

```
float _size=[file_size]; // Reads the file size

if(_size<100)    // File size is less than 100 MB
  {  exec mv [file] /A/* ; // Move to folder A }
else if(_size>500) // File size is greater than 500 MB
  {  exec mv [file] /C/* ; // Move to folder C }
else if((_size<=500)||(_size>=100)) //file size is between 100 to 500
  {  exec mv [file] /B/* ; // Move to folder C}
else
  {print("file error");}
```

So I hope it is easy to do. The above was just a general idea I would have done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to loop over all files in the current directory with this `for` loop:

```
for i in *; do
  size=$(stat --printf="%s" "$i")
  if [ $size -lt 100000000 ]; then
      mv "$i" A/
  elif [ $size -lt 500000000 ]; then
      mv "$i" B/
  else
      mv "$i" C/
  fi
done
```

You requested **Megabyte**, if you actually wanted 100/500 [**Mebibyte**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) use `104857600` and `524288000` accordingly.

If the directory contains other files and you just want to process e.g. `.avi` files, use:

```
for i in *.avi; do …
```

#### Explanations

- `for i in *; do … ; done` – loop over all files in the current directory
- `size=$(stat --printf="%s" "$i")` – get the file size in bytes using `stat` and save it as variable `size`
- `if A; then B; elif C; then D; else E; fi` – if A is true do B, else if C is true do D, else do E
- `[ $size -lt X ]` – test whether `size` is `l`ess `t`han X
- `mv "$i" Y/` – move the currently processed file inside folder Y

Comment: can you just mention #1. which syntax is used to read the file size ? , #2. Linux would show the file size in bits or bytes ?

Comment: @SIDDHARTH I'll add full explanations later, but for now: The output of `stat --printf="%s" "$i"` (where variable `i` holds the processed filename) is saved as variable `size`, `stat` prints lots of file information and the output can be controled with the `--printf` option, `%s` stands for “total size, in bytes” here. See [`man stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/stat.1.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can do this kind of thing with GNU `find` e.g.

```
find BB/ -type f \( -size -100M -exec mv -t A/ {} + \
  -o -size +500M -exec mv -t C/ {} + -o -exec mv -t B/ {} + \)
```

**NOTES:**

- If you want to move files *within the same tree* (e.g. `A/`, `B/`, `C/` are subdirectories of `BB`) then you will need to prevent `find` from recursing into these, using `-maxdepth` or `-prune` for example.
- Care is required due to the rounding behavior of `-size`. It's not a problem with this case, but for example `-size -1M` will round all files smaller than 1024kB up to 1M such that only empty files match.

Testing with kilobyte sized files for convenience:

```
$ tree -h somepath/
somepath/
├── [   0]  file0
├── [100K]  file100
├── [150K]  file150
├── [200K]  file200
├── [250K]  file250
├── [300K]  file300
├── [350K]  file350
├── [400K]  file400
├── [450K]  file450
├── [ 50K]  file50
├── [500K]  file500
├── [550K]  file550
└── [600K]  file600

0 directories, 13 files
```

then

```
$ find somepath/ -type f \( -size -100k -exec mv -vt A/ {} + \
>   -o -size +500k -exec mv -vt C/ {} + -o -exec mv -vt B/ {} + \)
'somepath/file50' -> 'A/file50'
'somepath/file0' -> 'A/file0'
'somepath/file550' -> 'C/file550'
'somepath/file600' -> 'C/file600'
'somepath/file250' -> 'B/file250'
'somepath/file200' -> 'B/file200'
'somepath/file100' -> 'B/file100'
'somepath/file300' -> 'B/file300'
'somepath/file500' -> 'B/file500'
'somepath/file350' -> 'B/file350'
'somepath/file450' -> 'B/file450'
'somepath/file400' -> 'B/file400'
'somepath/file150' -> 'B/file150'
```

giving

```
$ tree -h A B C
A
├── [   0]  file0
└── [ 50K]  file50
B
├── [100K]  file100
├── [150K]  file150
├── [200K]  file200
├── [250K]  file250
├── [300K]  file300
├── [350K]  file350
├── [400K]  file400
├── [450K]  file450
└── [500K]  file500
C
├── [550K]  file550
└── [600K]  file600

0 directories, 13 files
```

Comment: Just awesome, thank you for sharing! However as OP requests *MB* and (I suppose) has powers of 1000 in mind, is it right to use `-size -100000000c` (that's 100,000,000) for that? Btw `tree` has a `--sort=size` option.

Comment: @dessert yes they could use any of the suffixes listed in `man find` to get the exact sizes required

Comment: This is just another way to do that. This proves that there are multiple approach and ways to do the same things. As I previously mentioned,I had an idea that a proper script with find command and if-else would work supports my point of view.  Thanks to both steeldriver and @dessert to help me code the script.